# How to set input pattern?

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone please help me to set the correct input pattern for : when input starting digit is 2 then length is 17 digits if starts with 3 then length is 16 digits.

For example:

when input starts with number 2 then it must be: `pattern="\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{1}"`

But when input starts with number 3 it must be: `pattern="\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}"`

How to set pattern??

Comment: @wiktorstribizew so in my case it must be like this the i guess?   pattern="^(?:2\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}|3 \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{1})$"   because its must be like when start with 3 then 9999 9999 9999 9999 9 or start with 2 then 9999 9999 9999 9999

Comment: You mean you swapped `2` and `3` in your description? Then yes, just make sure the right digit is used. See my answer below, in `^(?:(2)|3)\d{3} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}(?(1) \d)$`, these digits are at the start of the pattern and can easily be adjusted.

Comment: @wiktorstribizew it works perfect thanks also for explaining, i have managed to fix a other problem aswell thanks to you! Perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to use two alternatives:

```
^(?:2\d{3} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d|3\d{3} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIJPKV/1).

The `^` matches the start of string, `2\d{3} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d` matches the numbers starting with `2`, `3\d{3} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}` matches the numbers starting with `3`.

However, in PHP PCRE regex, you can use conditionals. Here, you may shorten the pattern to

```
^(?:(2)|3)\d{3} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}(?(1) \d)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIJPKV/2). Here, `(?:(2)|3)` matches and captures into Group 1 the `2` digit, or matches `3`. The `(?(1) \d)` pattern checks if Group 1 matched, and if it did, a space and a digit are required at the end of the string.